# SOQL timeout when searching Contact by email

Tags: soql, rest-api

I have the following super simple query:

```
select id,email from Contact where email = '#{email}'
```

Our application integrates with SFDC via REST API. This query is timing out for some of our users but working perfectly for others. I assume it is timing out for users with high number of Contact records, since according to [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_query.htm) `Queries that take longer than two minutes to process will be timed out.`

This is really two questions:

1. What is the best way to find Leads and Contacts by their email?
2. After we find the Contact or Lead, we create a Task and associate it with that object. Is this the best practice on how to associate a Task with a Contact/Lead?

Thanks